# How to list devices connected to Mac's USB ports?

Tags: objective-c, usb

How do I list the devices connected to the mac and get their /dev/tty things in Objective C?

I would really love to do this for an application that I've been building for the past day or so.

I need to list the devices connected to the mac, and find one that will suit my criteria for this application. How do I find the devices, and list their /dev/tty's as NSStrings in a list?

Answer (score 2):

[Finding and Accessing Devices](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/AccessingHardware/AH_Finding_Devices/AH_Finding_Devices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000379-BAJDAJDJ) will get you additional information.

Answer (score -1):

The header file Mounter.h

```
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/ucred.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>
@interface Mounter : NSObject {

struct statfs *buf;
int i, count;
@private

}

-(void) getMountList;

@end
```

The implementation Mounter.m file:

```
#import "Mounter.h"


@implementation Mounter

-(void) getMountList {

  NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
  count = getmntinfo(&buf, 0);
  for (i=0; i<count; i++)
  {

        NSString *path = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:buf[i].f_mntonname];

        NSLog(@"Drivers: %@", path);
  }
```

Comment: I really don't see how this is relevant at all.